# Kernel-Power error (41) without anything wrong

Tags: windows, windows-8, power-supply, kernel, event-viewer

I'm using Windows 8.1 and after reboot/power on, I see Kernel-Power error (Event ID 41) on Event Viewer. It doesn't cause anything to happen for more than 2 years, no sudden reboots etc. but I wonder why it happens.

I checked my PSU (Seasonic x-850, 850w 80+ gold), it seems everything is fine with it. I don't use any GPU and when I stress-test all other things, all voltages seems right, no drops etc.

What else should I check? What can be the reason for this?

Comment: Is this logged *every* time you restart? Does it happen if you shut down, vs. reboot? Does it happen if you boot into Safe Mode, then shutdown/restart?

Comment: @TwistyImpersonator yes for all. But I've plugged out from surge protection and plugged into wall outlet and now it seems okay and doesn't create event log anymore. Also connected to UPS directly (which also has surge protection) and seems okay too. Looks like my other surge protection was the reason of this error but I'm not sure why. Will be nice if anyone can explain.

Comment: Did the problem surge protector have any sort of data connection to the computer, e.g. so that it could shut the PC down gracefully in the event of a power loss? Or is it just a plain surge protector?

Comment: @TwistyImpersonator it was just a plain surge protector. After plugging out power from this surge protector and testing it with others, I re-connected to it again and error wasn't re-occured too. Strange..

Comment: Odd. Maybe it *wasn't* the surge protector's fault. That would be an unusual conclusion in the first place, as it would require that the surge protector was cutting off power at some moment *during* (but only during) shutdown, but not during normal operation. Something like that occurring multiple times would be highly improbable...

Comment: @TwistyImpersonator I agree but I tried BIOS update, Windows configuration settings etc. and plugging out solved the problem. Maybe it was because of static electric? I can't tell, I hope anyone experienced with electronics may tell..

Comment: look at this Microsoft help page for tips about the issue: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2028504/en-us